# Переход по кнопке Submit

Tags: php, html

Есть `<input type="submit" name="button" value="РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ">`, после нажатия происходят действия на сервере(запись в бд) и после этого должно переходить на другую страницу. Как реализовать сам переход? этот блок находится в `<form id="slick-login" action="RegPage.php" method="post">`

Comment: RegPage.php
а на этой странице вы делаете запись в БД?, если да, то тогда можете просто делать в конце `header("Location: http://www.example.com/");`, а если это ajax запрос, то тогда посредством js отправляйте пользователя на нужную страницу

Comment: спасибо, всё работает)